# What's better: Constraint or FK? For a Status column

Tags: .net, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

I've an .NET app using Entity Framework 4 and SQL Server 2008 R2, where all the Data Access Layer will be managed by the EF4.

I've a table for financial transactions: **Transactions** with a column Status with possibles values: Opened, Released, Verified, Closed. This table will be very accessed all the time for insert, update and read. I need the better performance I can reach on this table.

The standard solution is to create a **TransactionStatuses** with Id(int), Name(varchar), and make relationship between **Transactions** and **TransactionStatuses**.

But now, I'm thinking in a different solution: Create only the **Transactions** table with a  column Status(int) and create a constraint where Status only accepts 1,2,3,4. And, on my app code create a Enumeration with Opened = 1, Released = 2, Verified = 3 and Closed = 4.

It's the second solution a better alternative from performance perspective?

Comment: Will you ever want to return the string names in your queries? Or provide any admin interface that allows editing the status names or adding new ones?

Comment: no, the names in Db are only for information. Admin interface will only use the status, will not edit or create new.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either will be fast; a constraint is *perhaps* easier to check, but databases are heavily optimised to make checking FK violations very very fast.

Given the two, I prefer the FK option from a maintenance perspective

- it is really easy to add a new status row via DML, vs changing a constraint which is (arguably) harder to deploy, requiring DDL
- you get the benefit of other metadata columns if needed - i.e. a description to go with the code, and perhaps soft-delete dates (for removing from the UI, without making old data invalid)

If the data will **never** change, then either approach is perfectly viable without prejudice.

Answer (score 4):

If your TransactionStatuses are immutable, and all you require is a single value (in this case, an integer correlating to an enum value), then yes, I would recommend you forget the extra TransactionStatuses table.

On the other hand, if you plan on attaching other information to a status that is pertinent to your business layer, or you plan on letting people customize statuses, then it should be an entity and thus have a table.